# Adding StructLayout attribute to F# type with implicit constructor

Tags: .net, f#, structlayout

I've got:

```
type Package =
    abstract member Date : int
    abstract member Save : unit -> unit

[<type:StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)>]
type Instant(date : int, value : int) =
    let mutable _date = date
    let mutable _value = value
    member X.Value : int = _value
    interface Package with    
        member X.Date : int = _date
        member X.Save() = ...
```

but getting error: **Only structs and classes without implicit constructors may be given the 'StructLayout' attribute**

so I realize it must be something alike:

```
type Instant =
    struct
        val Date : byte array
        ...
```

But this way I lost my interface. In C# for example adding `type:StructLayout` is possible for this type of classes (I think). How must I refactor my code to avoid this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message said, `StructLayout` should work with [explicit constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233233.aspx):

```
type Package =
    abstract member Date : int
    abstract member Save : unit -> unit

[<type:StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)>]
type Instant =
    val mutable Date: int
    val mutable Value: int
    new(date, value) = {Date = date; Value = value}

    interface Package with
        member x.Date = x.Date
        member x.Save() = x.Value |> ignore
```

If you have any further problem with `FieldOffset`, please take a look at code examples [here](http://apollo13cn.blogspot.dk/2012/02/f-warning-9.html).

Comment: The same as we did with Date, just use `x.Value`.

Comment: no, I'm getting strange error: This value is not a function and cannot be applied

Comment: another thing - I can't access Save from C#

Comment: 'NSL.Packages.Archive' does not contain a definition for 'Save' and no extension method 'Save' accepting a first argument of type 'NSL.Packages.Archive' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: 1. I can access `x.Value` (see my answer). 2. F# interfaces are explicit, so you need `(instant :> Package).Save()` or propagate the `Save()` method to the upper level in type declaration.